# IK working with object constraints

Tags: armature

I am making a robot, and I want its movement to be mechanical and stiff according to its hinges. I rigged the robot according to that and set constraints on the bones to limit their rotation, but when I add the IK, it doesn't respect the constraints. So is there a way to have IK respect the constraints or is there another way around?

Here's an image of the robot with the armature in case it can help you understand it better.

[image]

Comment: also i am using Blender 2.8

Answer (score 1):

The limits for IK solving are stored in the bones properties under *Inverse Kinematics*.

*Pose Mode > Properties Panel > Bone (Tab) > Inverse Kinematics (Section)*

[image: settings]